# Display timepicker in correct locale format

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, momentjs, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I am using [Bootstrap daterangepicker](http://www.daterangepicker.com/).
Moment JS is being used to set the locale for date formatting etc.

I would like to to show the timepicker based on the Moment JS locale.
Daterangepicker has a parameter for setting the picker format (12h/24h) at the initialization

> **timePicker24Hour: true** *(or false/no parameter for 12h format)*

How could I get locale information regarding the time format from Moment JS?
I could then set the proper timepicker type on init.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`moment.localeData`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/locale-data/) and the `longDateFormat` method to get locale specific information about time format. Then you can test if the format contains the `HH` (24 hours) token.

Here a live sample:

```js
function is24Hour(locale){
  var localeData = moment.localeData(locale);
  var hourFormat = localeData.longDateFormat('LT');
  return hourFormat.includes('HH');
}

console.log( is24Hour('en') );
console.log( is24Hour('it') );
console.log( is24Hour('fr') );
console.log( is24Hour('de') );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

*This may need further tests for other locales.*

Comment: Thanks, that's actually a pretty neat way of doing this. Never thought of breaking down the format string.

Comment: Let's just hope that those strings don't change anytime soon :)